# How do I display div's next to each other within a wrapper div?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a page wrapper div that holds everything. This page div is not full page, but 95% width and height with a border.

Within this I want to have three divs next to each other, like the three stooges, and then one below all of them.

How do I do this with CSS?

Comment: Can you share your code to help people answer?

Comment: code helps us Stooges :)

Comment: Depends on the properties you want to give these columns. More code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this ways I always use for website layout, including responsive layout.

CSS:

```css
.wraper{
   width: 95%;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
.one, .two, .three{
   display:block;
   width:33%;
   border: 1px solid green;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
.one{
   float:left;
}
.two{
   margin:0 auto;
}
.three{
   float:right;
}
.four{
   clear:both;
   display:block;
   width:100%;
   border:1px solid red;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wraper">
   <div class="one">1</div>
   <div class="three">3</div>
   <div class="two">2</div>
   <div class="four">4</div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/sesong11/pen/wKEgKw)

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick for me.  I did not know about the clear: both option, which has helped with several other items as well!

Comment: if it help, please check as correct answers and vote. :)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you want to display the div's you want in a row as `display: inline` in your CSS, so that's div 1,2, and 3.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="one">1</div>
   <div class="two">2</div>
   <div class="three">3</div>
   <div class="four">4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap{
   height: 95%;
   width: 95%;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

.one, .two, .three{
   display: inline;
   border: 1px solid green;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/Oyobza)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use float to have divs next to each other.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="stack">Stack</div>
      <div class="stack">Stack</div>
      <div class="stack">Stack</div>
      <div class="full">Full</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
}

.stack {
    display: block;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.full {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

You will need the clear to show the full sized one.